# Parsing of txt file with different IFS

Tags: arrays, bash, parsing

this is the situation into my file txt:

```
kevin \t password \t path \n

steve \t password \t path \n

etc...
```

how can I parse this kind of file to get names into an array, passwords into another array and idem for path?
I thought to use IFS variable, but I've problems to identify what is id or psw or path.

I started from this code:

```
old_IFS=$IFS

IFS=$'\t\n'

lines=($(cat MYFILE)) 

IFS=$old_IFS
```

or is better to use awk?

someone has an idea?

Comment: I can tell you how to get those values into arrays, but I could probably tell you something more interesting if I knew what you wanted to do with the arrays once you had them.

Comment: for each user-psw-path I want to launch ftp command

Comment: So you don't need arrays at all: You can do the ftp command for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while read loop:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read user password path
do
    users+=( "$user" )
    passwords+=( "$password" )
    paths+=( "$path" )
    echo "$user's password is $password, and their path is $path"
done < yourtextfile
```

Comment: These aren't some arrays =)

Comment: I tried this code under OS X 10.8 and SUSE Linux 11: the `users` variable is the whole line, whereas `password` and `path` are blank.

Comment: That's because your fields aren't tab separated, as per the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an inefficient approach that is nevertheless easy to read:

```
f() {
    local IFS=$'\n' # Don't wordsplit on just any whitespace. Newlines only
    names=( $(cut -d$'\t' -f1 < file) )
    passes=( $(cut -d$'\t' -f2 < file) )
    paths=( $(cut -d$'\t' -f3 < file) )
}
f
```

Comment: @thatotherguy true. Edited to wordsplit on newlines.